# NSMutableArray not being modified properly when manipulated in other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I have an NSMutableArray as a property in a view controller class, and this line is being used in two other classes. One of the classes manipulates the array (adds more objects to it) and another just reads from it. When one of the classes manipulates the array, it is not being modified in the view controller class, which it is instantiated in. Therefore, the third class is not getting the proper date it needs.

In the view controller class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *entityLines;
```

In other two classes:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *linesToDraw;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *linesForKey;
```

Array initialization:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Line graph";
        lineQuery = [[LineGraphQuery alloc] init];
        entityLines = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Modifying array:

```
     - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(data.namedEntityData.count > 0) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, LINE_WIDTH);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        [self clearAllLines];
        for(NSString *key in [data.namedEntityData allKeys]) {
            EntityLine *entityLine = [self getNamedEntityLineForName:key];
            if(!entityLine) {
                entityLine = [[EntityLine alloc] init];
                entityLine.name = key;
                entityLine.color = [self getRandomColor];
            }
            float intervalX = STARTING_INTERVAL_X;
            float lastRangeY = MIN_EVENT_COUNT_Y;

            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [entityLine.color CGColor]);
            NSArray *events = [data.namedEntityData objectForKey:key];
            NSInteger rangeDifference = data.endYear - data.beginYear;

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDateRangeIntervals; i++) {
                int startYearRange = data.beginYear + (i * (rangeDifference / numberOfDateRangeIntervals));
                int endYearRange = (i == numberOfDateRangeIntervals - 1) ? data.endYear : data.beginYear + ((i + 1) * (rangeDifference / numberOfDateRangeIntervals) - 1);
                int eventCount = [self getCountForEvents:events withBeginYear:startYearRange andEndYear:endYearRange];

                Line *line = [[Line alloc] init];
                line.begin = CGPointMake(intervalX, lastRangeY);
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.begin.x, line.begin.y);
                intervalX += intervalXIncrement;
                lastRangeY = [self getYCoordinateForEventCount:eventCount];
                line.end = CGPointMake(intervalX, lastRangeY);
                [entityLine addLine:line];

                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);
            }
            [linesToDraw addObject:entityLine];
        }

        [self drawEventCountLabelsWithContext:context];
        [self drawDateRangeLabelsWithContext:context];
    }
}

- (void)clearAllLines
{
    for(EntityLine *line in linesToDraw)
        [line clearLines];
}
```

Other class setting the reference to the NSMutableArray:

```
lineGraph.linesToDraw = self.entityLines;
lineKey.linesForKey = self.entityLines;
```

Comment: Post the code for how you're getting the array and modifying it.

Comment: Let's look at the obvious check first:  make sure that the pointers all point to the same object and are non-nil.

Comment: provide more details :)

Comment: You realize that giving objects the same name in different classes creates separate objects? You need to be passing the object pointer to the other two objects so they have a reference to your array. I don't see that happening here.

Comment: Are you sure giving the same name for objects creates separate objects? Can you please give me an example of what you recommend?

Comment: @user1530580: More precisely it creates separate *variables*. Two variables with the same name are not inherently related. You need to show how these are getting set, since it sounds like that's the problem.

Comment: *Please, please, please* study up on OBJECTS and POINTERS before you attempt any more Objective-C programming.  So far you're just cribbing examples, and you don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Are lineGraph and lineKey instances of your other two classes? If so, are you sure that those pointers point to the instances that you have  (or will have) on screen?

Comment: Yes, lineGraph and lineKey are instances of my other classes. They are just UIView's so yep.

Comment: Are these views subviews of the view controller with the above code, or are they in separate view controllers? Your overall structure is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, the views are separate classes that are instantiated in the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Giving properties (or instance variables) the same name in different classes does not cause them to point to the same objects. After creating your array, you need to pass a pointer to the array to the property in the other class instances.

```
@interface ABCFirstClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *lines;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ABCAnotherClass *otherClass;  // Also has a property named "lines".

@end


@implementation ABCFirstClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.lines = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
        self.otherClass = [[ABCAnotherClass alloc] init];
        self.otherClass.lines = self.lines;
          // Now both classes have a pointer to the same array object.
    }
    return self;
}
```

This doesn't need to happen in the -init method. Maybe a totally different class gets the pointer from one and passes it to the other.

Note that I'd normally work with the ivars directly in -init (_lines, _otherClass), but I wanted to keep this example simple.

Comment: In general, objects don't have names.  Variables have names, and two different variables with the same name do not inherently point to the same object.

Comment: You're right, I picked the wrong words there. Edited.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as the example above. I even changed it so all the different NSMutableArray's have different names now. Still the same problem.  lineGraph.linesToDraw = self.entityLines;

Comment: Does the array exist when you pass it to the other objects?

Comment: Somehow I suspect that you don't extract the otherClass property and use that as your ABCAnotherClass object.

Comment: Of course. The array is initialized in the first class' constructor. For the previous commenters, I understand objects... Objective-C is not my strongest language but if I am doing something wrong, please inform me rather than belittling me.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the first class must retain the array. Since the other classes have weak references, if the first class releases it the other classes will also lose their reference to the array.

Comment: Well, I'm using ARC. The first class (the one instantiating it) has a strong reference to the array.

Comment: We're not trying to belittle you at all. There are users of all different levels here. Just trying to be clear. Can you post the code where you pass create the array, then pass it to the other classes?

Comment: Oh I didn't mean that to you. That was for others here. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just added the code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I'm still not seeing where you create the array instance. And it's getting a little more confusing because your last post is using different property names than the code above it.

Comment: Just added the init method and renamed the line variables. Hope that helps.

Comment: I went through the debugger again. The memory addresses for the array in all three classes are the same. Clearly, it is not a pointer issue. I believe it is something I am doing incorrectly with ARC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30357/discussion-between-dave-batton-and-user1530580)